# JMeter uses only first line of CSV settings

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have JMeter project:

```
- HTTP Request Defaults
- HTTP Header Manager
- CSV Data Set Config
  (filename = my.tsv, variable names = myVar,..., delimiter = \t, others default)
- Thread group
--- Loop Controller
----- HTTP Request (uses ${myVar})
----- Timer
----- View Results Tree
```

The issue is that only first line of my.tsv is used by JMeter to generate requests. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you define multiple threads, It should pick the values from the `tsv` file. each thread picks different value until all the rows consumed and will repeat the records for next threads/iterations.

If you are looking for Loop Controller, in multiple loops and single thread, then JMeter uses the same value picked in first iteration for remaining iterations.